# Looping through two lists, comparing one list against the other and return values

Tags: python, list, loops

I have two lists that I want to compare.  I want to loop through list one values and compare it to the values in list two.  Im looking to return either 1, 0, or -1 based on if the value in list one is less than or equal to the value in list two.

For example, the value of 2 from list one would be assigned a value of 0 because it is greater than 0 and less than 3 from list two.

```
list_one = [0,2,5,0,3,7]
list_two = [0,3]

#loop through list one values
for j in list_one:
    #loop through list two values
    for k in list_two:
        
        if float(j) <= k:
            value = 1
            break            
        elif float(j) <= k:
            value = 0 
            break
        else:
            value = -1
            
    print(value)
```

Actual Outcome:

```
1
1
-1
1
1
-1
```

Expected Outcome:

```
1
0
-1
1
0
-1
```

Comment: You're checking the same condition twice...?

Comment: What is the purpose of `float` conversion?

Comment: I was thinking since there are two values in list_two, it would have to loop through twice.  If the first criteria is met, it would break and end the loop, if not it would move onto the next one and if met would break, etc.. I'm guessing that's not the right mind set here.

Comment: The 'float' is artifact from actual code and has no meaning in this example.

Comment: Your `elseif` condition is the same as your `if` condition so will never be executed

Comment: will you explain how the expected output was derived? show the comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few issues in your logic, I have changed them in the code attached below

```
list_one = [0,2,5,0,3,7]
list_two = [0,3]

#loop through list one values
for j in list_one:
    #loop through list two values
    value=0
    for k in list_two:
        
        if float(j) <= k:
            value += 1
            break            
        elif float(j) == k:
            value += 0 
            break
        else:
            value += -1
            
        if value > 1:
            value = 1
        elif value < -1:
            value = -1
            
    print(value)
```

Let me know if this fixes it for you, the problem statement wasn't very clear, I have modified this code according to my interpretation of the problem statement

Comment: Thanks, that worked and makes sense! Next time, I'll try posting something with a clearer problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

#Logic errors aside, the biggest mistake in this code sample is your confusing use of #list_two. Clearly list_two must be a 2-element list: [min, max]. Any other structure #would be difficult to understand. Keep it as a list if you prefer but at the outset #decode list_two as follows:""

```
 min_val = list_two[0]
 max_val = list_two[1]
```

#Then loop j through list_one and apply this logic:

```
if j < min_val:
    value = 1
elif j > max_val:
    value = -1
else:
    value = 0
```

#So basically lose the second loop (the k loop). And definitely remove the float() #references.